# hyperledger fabric couchdb data

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

Background:

I am developing blockchain network(Hyperledger fabric v1.1).
For continuous use,I persist couchdb data（/opt/couchdb/data）.

Issue:

I don't know what these data shows.（below）

1. _replicator.xxxxxxxxxx.couch
2. _users.xxxxxxxxxx.couch
3. mychannel_.xxxxxxxxxx.couch
4. mychannel_lscc.xxxxxxxxxx.couch
5. my channel_mycc.xxxxxxxxxx.couch

Please tell me that these data shows.

Sincerely.

Comment: The last one has the actual data you invoke. The others are mostly housekeeping (internal) things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Excuse me.May I ask additional question?.
If these data is not persist and during the rebuilding by refreshing container, what will happen by accessing the couchdb (for example, query or invoke)?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "refreshing container"---does it mean restarting all peers? Some peers? or destroying and recreating containers?

Comment: destroying and recreating all peers. but peer's data is persisted.

Comment: The general expectation is CouchDB's data is also persisted if Peer's data is persisted. I think (i'll need to double check) if Couch data is not persisted, the Couch will rebuild itself upon startup.